# Extra "null" at end of string

Tags: arduino, esp32

I've been using Arduino to try to store a file in Spiffs and read it back later. When I print it, I get what I expect, when I add it to a string I end up with "null" after what I expect. Any idea of what to change?

Here is the code:

```html
File file = SPIFFS.open("/myfile.txt");
String response;
while(file.available()){
  response=file.readStringUntil('\n');
  file.close();
  file = SPIFFS.open("/myfile.txt");
  Serial.println(file.readStringUntil('\n'));
  Serial.println(response);
}
```

Here is the response:

```
This is a testnull
This is a test
```

Answer (score 1):

The file handling in the loop is buggy - the operations of opening, reading and closing the file are interleaved with checking if the file is available for reading. Don't mix those. This is how it should look like:

```
File file = SPIFFS.open("/myfile.txt");
String response;
while(file.available()) {
  response = file.readStringUntil('\n');
  Serial.println(response);
}
file.close();
```

Comment: I realized that when working on it some more. I did change it like you suggested, but my main issue still persists. when I read the file to a string variable I get an extra null while when I print straight to serial I get what I put in.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with the reading of the file. It was with the writing. I had

```
file.print(mystring);
```

and replacing it with

```
file.println(mystring);
```

solved my issue.